# NameError: undefined local variable or method `user'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, rspec, rspec-rails

I'm writing an app using RoR, using gem Devise for user authentication. I'm trying to test user behaviour when he signed in the app and have next error:

```
User::TransactionsController when logged in when its own record GET #show assigns the requested instance as @instance
     Failure/Error: let(:transaction) { FactoryGirl.create(:transaction, user_id: user.id) }

     NameError:
       undefined local variable or method `user' for #<RSpec::ExampleGroups::UserTransactionsController::WhenLoggedIn::WhenItsOwnRecord::GETShow:0x00000004d77220>
```

My tests start with:

```
RSpec.describe User::TransactionsController, type: :controller do
  render_views

  before { sign_in FactoryGirl.create :user }

  let(:transaction_category) { FactoryGirl.create(:transaction_category) }
  let(:transaction) { FactoryGirl.create(:transaction, user_id: user.id) }
  ......
end
```

My factory:

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :transaction do
    date '2016-01-08'
    comment 'MyString'
    amount 1
    transaction_category

    trait :invalid do
      amount nil
    end
  end
end
```

My TransactionsController looks like:

```
class User::TransactionsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :authenticate_user!
  before_action :find_transaction, only: [:show, :edit, :destroy, :update]

  def new
    @transaction = current_user.transactions.build
  end

  def show
  end

  def create
    @transaction = current_user.transactions.build(transaction_params)
    if @transaction.save
      redirect_to user_transaction_url(@transaction)
    else
      render :new
    end
  end

  def index
    @transactions = current_user.transactions
  end

  def edit
  end

  def destroy
    @transaction.destroy
    redirect_to user_transactions_url
  end

  def update
    if @transaction.update(transaction_params)
      redirect_to user_transaction_url
    else
      render :edit
    end
  end

  private

  def transaction_params
    params.require(:transaction).permit(:amount, :date, :comment,
                                        :transaction_category_id)
  end

  def find_transaction
    @transaction = current_user.transactions.find(params[:id])
  end
end
```

Thanks!

Comment: Variable to user is missing. Create one: let(:user) { FactoryGirl.create :user } and use it in before block too.

Comment: @Šaras, thanks! Thats worked. But in my first variant isn't it defined by `before { sign_in FactoryGirl.create :user }`?

Comment: In `before` block you are creating another user and variable to it is not being saved anywhere. Basically, everytime you execute `FactoryGirl.create :user` you are creating a new unique user. Thus if you want have one user with transaction attached to him and also sign in as him too you need to create one in `let` block so that it could be used both for sign in and new transaction creation. @verrom

Comment: @Šaras, thanks a lot!! :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to define user

```
RSpec.describe User::TransactionsController, type: :controller do


render_views
  user = FactoryGirl.create( :user )
  before { sign_in( user ) }

  let(:transaction_category) { FactoryGirl.create(:transaction_category) }
  let(:transaction) { FactoryGirl.create(:transaction, user_id: user.id) }
  ......
end
```